# properties file to json

Tags: json, properties

Yes I'm lazy .. =) do you know of a working properties file to json converter?

I got something like

prop1=bla

pro2=bla bla

and want to get a json out of it magically =)

Comment: "Give me teh codez" is not a valid question format for StackOverflow.

Comment: I guess google is broken again...

Comment: stop being lazy, get off your ass, and do your job. Why should we help you if you can't be bothered to do anything?

Comment: WOW guys I was looking for an online tool that would do that ... enough with the negative feedback! I can code and do my job just don't like doing tedious things by hand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed -e 's/^\([^=]*\)\s*=\s*\(.*\)/"\1": "\2",/'` will get you most of the way there, assuming it's formatted as you say above.