# regex to convert custom property file to json key value pair representation

Tags: regex

I have a partial solution to convert this

```
USERNAME=CONSTANT[myUserName]
PASSWORD=CONSTANT[mypwd]
```

to

```
 "USERNAME":"myUserName",
 "PASSWORD":"mypwd"
```

I see a similar solution here 
 [properties file to json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649400/properties-file-to-json). Basically I am looking for zero or more spaces 1.) anywhere before or after a key 2.) before and after = sign

```
  USERNAME  =      CONSTANT[myUserName]
    PASSWORD   =  CONSTANT[mypwd]
```

**Find What:** `(^[^ \t]+)(\s.*=\s*CONSTANT\[)(.*[^\n])(\])`

**Replace:** `"$1":"$2",`

```
 "USERNAME":"myUserName",
 "PASSWORD":"mypwd",
```

Also I want to make sure I do this for each line and some times it matches multiple lines which is wrong. I hope one can find a solution that works in Eclipse on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use `^` and `$` in order to avoid your regex matching multiple lines. Try something like this:

```
^\s*(\w+)\s*?\=\s*?\w+\[(\w+)\]$
```

Replace with:

```
"$1":"$2",
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/mxF8lI/1/

Comment: This works but it does not work with Eclipse IDE on Windows where I am trying to do find replace.